# What are the advantages Laravel form syntax

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am learning Laravel as my first framework, I saw, they have own syntax for create forms eg:

Laravel Inputs:

```
    {{ Form::text('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'Email')) }}
    {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
```

HTML Inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

what are the advantages, I can get, if i use Laravel syntax for create forms? thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are many advantages of using the Laravel syntax.

1. The Laravel Form automatically adds CSRF protection .
2. You can autofill form easily using the Form::model() instead of the plain PHP.
3. Your code remains clean and consistent and is not filled with a mix of HTML and PHP
4. It gives extensibility i.e others can dynamically insert form elements.
   This is useful only if you are building a software for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

- Cleaner syntax. Compare for example a traditional HTML select vs using [`Form::select('name', $array)`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists).
- Integrated [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection.
- Integrated URLs to named routes, actions and RESTful controllers of your application. If use routes in your form URL and you cange a route URL all your models will still work.
- [Form Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding) to populate form with data from your models.
- Automatic form fields population with flash (old) input.
- Extendable and customizable with macros. Think if all your fields need a class but that class may change on future. If you use a macro to set that class when it changes in the future you only have to update one line of code instead of all your views.
- Possible integration with popular CSS frameworks to add their look and field + automatic error appending. [example](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/zurb-foundation-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's [Blade synta](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates)x based on ASP.NET's Razor can be very useful because it allows for template inheritance and it has useful syntax sugar for control structures like `if` and `for` and it helps with CSRF by assigning a token to your forms and verifying it when they're posted. Also it allows you to bind your model to a form and have the framework itself worry about filling out all the form fields. You can also even extend it by defining your own custom control structures.